# Problem in giving search functionality using downloaded ArcGIS JavaScript API v4.27

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to use search functionality using downloaded ArcGIS JavaScript API v4.27. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum- 
  scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
  <title>Test local installation of ArcGIS Maps SDK for 
  JavaScript</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <!-- Load the ArcGIS CSS directly from the CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./esri/themes/light/main.css" />

  <!-- Load the ArcGIS SDK script directly from the CDN -->
  <script src="./init.js"></script>

      <script>
      require([
      "esri/config",
      "esri/Basemap",
      "esri/layers/TileLayer",
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/SceneView",
      "esri/widgets/Search" // Add the Search module 
       ], function (esriConfig,Basemap, TileLayer, Map, SceneView, 
       Search) {

       esriConfig.assetsPath ="/assets";

       const layer = new TileLayer({
        url: "https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"
      });
      const customBasemap = new Basemap({
        baseLayers: [layer],
        title: "My Basemap"
      });
      const myMap = new Map({
        basemap: customBasemap
      });
      const view = new SceneView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: myMap
      });

      // Add a Search widget to the view's UI
      const search = new Search({
        view: view
      });
      view.ui.add(search, "top-right");

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  <div id="logDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting this error:

> Using ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript 4.27 [Date: 20230626, Revision:
> b81703b4] [esri.widgets.Attribution] widget-intl:locale-error
> esri.widgets.Attribution q {name: 'intl:message-bundle-error',
> details: {…}, message: 'Errors occurred while loading
> "esri/widgets/Attribution/t9n/Attribution"'} [esri.widgets.Zoom]
> widget-intl:locale-error esri.widgets.Zoom q {name:
> 'intl:message-bundle-error', details: {…}, message: 'Errors occurred
> while loading "esri/widgets/Zoom/t9n/Zoom"'}
> [esri.widgets.NavigationToggle] widget-intl:locale-error
> esri.widgets.NavigationToggle q {name: 'intl:message-bundle-error',
> details: {…}, message: 'Errors occurred while loading
> "esri/widgets/NavigationToggle/t9n/NavigationToggle"'}
> [esri.widgets.Compass] widget-intl:locale-error esri.widgets.Compass q
> {name: 'intl:message-bundle-error', details: {…}, message: 'Errors
> occurred while loading "esri/widgets/Compass/t9n/Compass"'}
> [esri.widgets.Search] widget-intl:locale-error esri.widgets.Search q
> {name: 'intl:message-bundle-error', details: {…}, message: 'Errors
>
> ...
>
> (d:\Rakesh\arcgis_js_v427_api\arcgis_js_v427_api\arcgis_js_api\javascript\4.27\init.js:1717:169)
> at a.when
> (d:\Rakesh\arcgis_js_v427_api\arcgis_js_v427_api\arcgis_js_api\javascript\4.27\init.js:2638:266)
> [esri.views.3d.environment.Stars] q {name: 'request:server', details:
> {…}, message: 'Failed to fetch'}
>
> undefined.(d:\Rakesh\arcgis_js_v427_api\arcgis_js_v427_api\arcgis_js_api\javascript\4.27\init.js:1717:82) at t

What is the reason for the error and the fix?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Providing the error mesage is not enough, kindly give more context to your problem.

Comment: I updated it with code

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say why it doesn't work for you since you are getting libraries and assets from local path.

The below code works for me without any problems:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Linked Maps Example</title>
  <!-- Include ESRI JavaScript API -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.23/esri/themes/light/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.23/"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height:100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  <script>
    require([
      "esri/config",
      "esri/Basemap",
      "esri/layers/TileLayer",
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/SceneView",
      "esri/widgets/Search"
    ],
    function (esriConfig,Basemap, TileLayer, Map, SceneView, Search) {
//      esriConfig.assetsPath ="/assets"; 
      const layer = new TileLayer({
        url: "https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"
      });
      const customBasemap = new Basemap({
        baseLayers: [layer],
        title: "My Basemap"
      });
      const myMap = new Map({
        basemap: customBasemap
      });
      const view = new SceneView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: myMap
      });    
      const search = new Search({
        view: view
      });
      view.ui.add(search, "top-right");
    }
  );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a sample of search with the above code:

[image]

Is seems there's something wrong with your local install of ArcGIS JavaScript API library.

**UPDATE**:
It worked for me also with local install of ArcGIS JS library. I installed it on subdirectory `api/4.27` of my app on IIS server and referenced it like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="api/4.27/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
<script src="api/4.27/init.js"></script>
```

Did you successfully run test `index.html` from the installed library after installation?

Comment: Try this code by downloading arcgis javascript api 4.27. It is working with online links but not with the offline package.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line about

> esriConfig.assetsPath ="/assets";

That property is [only](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-config.html#assetsPath) for use with NPM packages.  If you downloaded the API library zip file from https://developers.arcgis.com/downloads/, then you SHOULD NOT set this variable.

Comment: Even then it is producing same error.

Comment: Issue solved folder placing was incorrect